# Routine Tests on Motor

Tags: voltage, current, motor, induction-motor, testing

I was going through the standards related to motor testing that are IS 12615, IS 15999-1, IS 15999-2-1 while reviewing a motor with requirements of 3phase induction motor, 1500rpm, 120hp, 415V and delta connected.

I observed that there are requirements specified for

1. Insulation resistance (less than 30 Mohm)
2. HV test (1000+2*rated voltage for 1min)
3. Reduced voltage test (Apply 1/sqrt3 of rated value and check ability to run at rated speed)

But there are no requirements specified for

1. Stator resistance
2. Speed (The rated speed is 1500rpm but I am getting a motor with speed 1460rpm, is it acceptable?)
3. No load test
4. Locked rotor test.

I would really appreciate if you could clarify what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rated speed is not 1500 RPM, that is the synchronous speed. The no-load speed should be quite close to the synchronous speed even at reduced voltage. If the rated speed is 1460 RPM, that is the speed for full-voltage, full-load operation. That requires a dynamometer to check. The reduced voltage test is probably the only no-load test that is part of routine testing. The locked-rotor test is probably not part of routine testing. The manufacturer may have an acceptable range of current that can be checked as part of the reduced voltage test. However if the standard doesn't specify that that should be checked, it is not a requirement to check it.